# Invalid identifier order by sql command after a union

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tried to find a similar question but I can't. We are just trying to do a simple query with a union, and we get the 'invalid identifier' error on the final line. Does anyone know how to organize the parenthesis to make this valid? We have tried so many ways.

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.CID
FROM Enrollments E, Students S
WHERE E.SID = S.SID AND (S.Major <> 'CS' OR S.Major IS NULL) 
GROUP BY E.CID
HAVING 10 > COUNT (*)
UNION SELECT DISTINCT C.CID
              FROM COURSES C
              MINUS 
       SELECT DISTINCT E3.CID 
              FROM Enrollments E3, Students S2
              WHERE E3.SID = S2.SID 
              GROUP BY E3.CID
              HAVING 0 < COUNT (*)
ORDER BY E.CID DESC;
```

error message :

> ERROR at line 14:
>
> ORA-00904: "E"."CID": invalid identifier

EDIT: Just so you know what the purpose is, all classes with less than 10 non CS majors along with all empty classes.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT since your GROUP BY's eliminates all duplicates. No need to do SELECT DISTINCT since UNION eliminates all duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are selecting `E.CID`
2. Then you are creating an union with another query where you are selecting `C.CID`
3. In the order by clause you have a result where the column is named `CID` and not `E.CID`
4. And to add to this, as **The Impelar** comented, regarding the column `E.CID` in the group by clause:

   > "E.CID does not exist at the level of the last line. It's exists in the scope of the first query only (lines 1-5)"

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT E.CID
   FROM Enrollments E, Students S
   WHERE E.SID = S.SID AND (S.Major <> 'CS' OR S.Major IS NULL) 
   HAVING 10 > COUNT (*)              
   GROUP BY E.CID  
   UNION SELECT DISTINCT C.CID
                FROM COURSES C
         MINUS 
         SELECT DISTINCT E3.CID 
                FROM Enrollments E3, Students S2
                WHERE E3.SID = S2.SID 
          GROUP BY E3.CID
          HAVING 0 < COUNT (*)
   ORDER BY CID DESC;
   ```

[Here is a demo without error](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3c001428f3cfd6f883c383fa32aeb315)

Comment: To add the explanation: `E.CID` does not exist at the level of the last line. It does exist in the scope of the first query only (lines 1-5). Very good. +1

Comment: Hi @DevonF, was this answer of any help to you ? If it is please up vote. Was the answer correct and it fixes your error (Ibelieve it does). Then you can accept the answer as correct and give it up vote. Cheers!